# android create big scalable vector image programmatically

Tags: android

I have a task to create programmatically and display a big rectangular box consists of about 1.000 boxes. Whole image has to be scalable and each box has to be clickable. What is the best way / lib for my task? I need a good performance realization. And will it works fast on average budget device?

Comment: Use RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager

Comment: Try this tutorial from [AndroidHive](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/04/android-glide-image-library-building-image-gallery-app/)

Comment: Jai, Good advice, but can RecyclerView be scallable? I need to zoom it.